# Distribution 50% of trees concentrated near one point of park, other 50% just cover the park

Tags: distributions

Could you please suggest a distribution that could satisfy the next requirement?
Distribution 50% of trees concentrated near one point of park, other 50% just cover the park(not concentrated). Using [x,y] coordinates

Comment: I choosed a way to randomly choose the place in the park. Assigned to this place 50% of trees and, uniformly distributed other 50% of trees among left places in the park.
What are your suggestions? Could be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your "concentrated" area a grove, and the entire area the park.  The grove must have some area of it's own, and a tree generated at random anywhere in the park has probability `P(grove) = Area(grove) / Area(park)` of being within the grove.  Your algorithm to place a tree would then be:

```
Generate U distributed Uniform(0,1)
If U < 0.5 - P(grove)
    Generate a tree in the grove
Else
    Generate a tree uniformly anywhere in the park
```

Lather, rinse, and repeat for as many trees as you wish.

Note that the `Else` clause includes the grove, which accounts for the proportion of trees being deducted from 1/2 the `If` clause.  Also note that this presumes the grove represents less than half of the park, since otherwise putting 50% of the trees in more than 50% of the grounds would would make them *less* concentrated within the grove than outside.

Alternatively, if you want exactly 50% you can plunk trees randomly throughout the park and count how many land *outside* the grove.  Once that count hits 50% of your total, generate trees only within the grove.